# number of results in google geocomplete places results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

Hello my question is regarding google map api.
I am creating a autocomplete search bar with google map api. but the problem is that it is returning only five results. Can anybody tell me how to increase number of results.
my code is below

```
<script src="js/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>

<script>

$('#geocomplete').keydown(function(e) {

  $(function(){
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.50,0.1167);

    $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
      map: ".map_canvas",
      country: 'gb',
types: ["(regions)"]
    });

    var map =  $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("map")

    map.setCenter(center);

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can make it more than 5 result at the same time.

Comment: hey so can you tell me any other api so that i  can get upto 10 results

Answer (score 6):

This question has been asked many times before. Visit Google's Place Autocomplete page [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results) and you'll see the text:

> The Places API returns up to 5 results.

So there's your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get the number of results returned for each query?

Comment: @zero_cool something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538358/jquery-ui-autocomplete-count-results ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.google place autocomplete result has the length 5.